# Displaying Google Maps in OpenJUMP

Tags: google-maps, openjump

I am creating a GIS application using [OpenJUMP](http://www.openjump.org/). I would like to show Google Maps as the base layer on top of which other spatial data is being rendered using PostGIS database.

How can I go about integrating Google Maps in the OpenJUMP application?

Answer (score 1):

OpenJUMP does not have any support for tiled map services at the moment. Contact OpenJUMP developers through openjump-dev mailing list and file a feature request at http://sourceforge.net/p/jump-pilot/feature-requests/?source=navbar.